# Regex: Detect any substring of the alphabet?

Tags: regex, oracle

First step

- With "the alphabet" defined as `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, I want to find any substring of the alphabet. I need to build more from here, but this is my first challenge.

End-goal

- Given a pattern of characters (A-Z) with no repetitions and no whitespace and only incrementing characters (ABDE, never ABED), replace all missing characters in the alphabet with a single space within an Oracle statement. So, a column of a row might read `ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXYZ` (F and RS are missing) and it needs to read `ABCDE GHIJKLMNOPQ  TUVWXYZ`.

Is this even possible?

David

Comment: It seems to me like it would be easier to do with plain old SQL than with a regular expression. Start by creating a table containing a row for each letter of the alphabet, and see what you can come up with from that.

Comment: I don't see where you're going with this.

I edited the question to read "a column of a row" instead of "a column of a table". Does that change your understanding of my question at all?

Comment: Are you saying `AZ` needs to be replaced with `A + <24 spaces> + Z` ?

Comment: Yes. And `Z` needs to be replaced with `<25 spaces> + Z`. Can't even guarantee the `A` and `Z` are there

Comment: RegEx may not be the best tool..but depending on how you plan on implementing it, this could help: [`^(A)?(B)?(C)?(D)?(E)?(F)?$`](http://regex101.com/r/oF2kZ4/1)

Comment: This is not a pattern problem. Its a code problem.

Comment: Is it a requirement that regex is used? I agree that this is a code problem.

Comment: @Sam: I'm not sure how to use that. Can you expand what you would do with it?

Comment: @sln: agreed. This would be much easier in code - but this must be done in SQL. At the moment, my only solution involves a very long case statement

Comment: In the end, my solution would still need to have code to back up the substitution. Pretty much the expression will capture `A` or null into group 1, `B` or null into group 2, etc. Then you can check your groups and if the group is null, insert a space. This will also fail on invalid strings like `ZA` or `ABC123`.

Comment: I didn't say you can't match sequential alphabet chars, but you have to analyze the results to make up the replacement. That's code. Can you do code?

Comment: This sounds like a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain the underlying problem what exactly you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @DavidZemon Can we see your "very long case statement"? With Oracle I wouldn't rule out the possibility that your solution is better than using regex functions.

Comment: In C this would be done like starting with a result string of 26 spaces. Loop through input string `pResult[(*pInput) - 'A'] = *pInput; pInput++;` doing some bounds checking.

Comment: The replacement can be performed in SQL with Oracle's regex functions (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1007573). Also, sorry about that - I should have specified Oracle. This is being used to create a view in oracle - no wrapper code calling the SQL function so no, Java/Python/C++ wrapper won't do any good.

Comment: Not homework. Sort of an XY problem, but doesn't matter because the solution is non-negotiable. No - it's not a good format. Yes, I'd love to do it differently. No, i don't have a choice.

Comment: Regex is not required. All that's required is that we create a view that contains a column based on the above requirements. I was hoping there was some way to simplify that with regex. @Bacs, I'm working on getting the case statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single value you can use two connect-by clauses; one to generate 26 values, the other to split the original string into individual characters. Since the ASCII codes are consecutive, the `ascii()` function can be used to generate a number from 1-26 for each of the characters that are present. Then left-join the two lists:

```
var str varchar2(26);
exec :str := 'ABCDFGZ';

with alphabet as (
  select level as pos
  from dual connect by level <= 26
),
chars as (
  select substr(:str, level, 1) character,
    ascii(substr(:str, level, 1)) - 64 as pos
  from dual connect by level <= length(:str)
)
select listagg(nvl(chars.character, ' '))
  within group (order by alphabet.pos) as result
from alphabet
left outer join chars on chars.pos = alphabet.pos;

RESULT                   
--------------------------
ABCD FG                  Z
```

This is with an SQL*Plus bind variable to avoid repeating the string, but it could be plugged in from somewhere else.

It's a bit more complicated to create a view as the multiple rows from the table can cause problems with the connect-by. The list of possible values has to include a primary (or unique, at least) key from the table, and the original string if you want to include that (and any other columns you want from the table). The split list needs to also include the primary key, and that needs to be included in the outer join.

```
create view v42 as
with possible as (
  select id, str, level as pos
  from t42
  connect by level <= 26
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
),
actual as (
  select id, substr(str, level, 1) character,
    ascii(substr(str, level, 1)) - 64 as pos
  from t42
  connect by level <= length(str)
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
select possible.id, possible.str, listagg(nvl(actual.character, ' '))
  within group (order by possible.pos) as result
from possible
left outer join actual on actual.id = possible.id and actual.pos = possible.pos
group by possible.id, possible.str;
```

Then with some sample data, `select * from v42` gives:

```
        ID STR                        RESULT                   
---------- -------------------------- --------------------------
         1 A                          A                          
         2 Z                                                   Z 
         3 AZ                         A                        Z 
         4 ABCDFGZ                    ABCD FG                  Z 
         5 ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXYZ    ABCDE GHIJKLMNOPQ  TUVWXYZ
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5227d/1).

It might be a little cleaner with a recursive CTE instead. Or with a function that works on one value at a time. Or with a regex, of course...

[Here's a recursive CTE version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a0b5/1), for fun:

```
create view v42 as
with possible(id, str, pos, character) as (
  select id, str, 1, 'A'
  from t42
  union all
  select id, str, pos + 1, chr(64 + pos + 1)
  from possible
  where pos < 26
),
actual (id, str, pos, character) as (
  select id, str, 1, substr(str, 1, 1)
  from t42
  union all
  select id, str, pos + 1, substr(str, pos + 1, 1)
  from actual
  where pos < length(str)
)
select possible.id, possible.str, listagg(nvl(actual.character, ' '))
  within group (order by possible.pos) as result
from possible
left outer join actual
on actual.id = possible.id
and actual.character = possible.character
group by possible.id, possible.str;
```

(SQL Fiddle does odd things with spacing, so view as plaintext output, from the 'Run SQL' drop-down.)

Comment: I'm still evaluating your complete answer. In the meantime:

Your embedded results here on StackOverflow show the correct number of spaces, but the linked SQL Fiddle does not. Is this a SQL Fiddle problem or a problem with the posted code?

Comment: @DavidZemon - that's SQL Fiddle; try looking at the plaintext output (form the 'Run SQL' button/drop-down combo control). Let me know if I haven't explained anything though.

Comment: Man, you seems to be a consistent hard worker to give such a detailed answer. kuddos!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - beats real work *8-) And not sure why I overcomplicated the first version with `ascii()`; your version comparing chars is simpler, and I ended up doing that in the recursive version anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity tried this..

```
WITH FULL_ALPHABETS AS
  (
    SELECT CHR(64+level) alpha,rownum AS id
      FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL<=26
  ),
INPUT_ALPHABETS AS
  (
    SELECT SUBSTR(UPPER('ABCDEFYZ'),level,1) alpha, rownum AS id
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(UPPER('ABCDEFYZ'))
  )
SELECT LISTAGG(NVL(I.ALPHA,' ')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY F.ALPHA)
  FROM FULL_ALPHABETS F
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INPUT_ALPHABETS I
     ON (F.ALPHA = I.ALPHA)
ORDER BY F.ALPHA;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Important note:** This way doesn't work with Oracle since the lookaround feature is not supported.

You can do it with a little tricky way:

1. first, you concatenate `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` with a newline character and your string.
2. you use this pattern to perform the substitution with a space `(?!([A-Z]+)(?=.*\1))[A-Z]` *(use a dotall modifier to allow the dot to match newline characters)*
3. split the string on the newline character and keep the first part

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oJ1dU7/1)

Comment: @sln: Thanks, but unfortunately, the lookarounds don't seem to exist in oracle regexes.

Comment: Trying to find how to integrate with Oracle!

Comment: I'm also not seeing a dotall modifier in Oracle. Anyone found that yet?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: Not sure it is possible.

Comment: @DavidZemon: you can avoid the dotall modifier by replacing `.` with `[\s\S]`

Comment: That's a good point. Solves that problem at least.

But, no matter. No lookarounds :(

Comment: I've marked it as useful though as I think a lot of other readers might use it for other languages

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working with 10g, so don't have LISTAGG. My approach is similar to others so far, but I came up with this. I should mention that WM_CONCAT is not supported by Oracle, if that's something that troubles you.

```
select replace(wm_concat(OUTPUT_CHAR),',') OUTPUT_STRING 
from
  (select nvl(INPUT_STRING.INPUT_CHAR,' ') OUTPUT_CHAR
   from 
    (select chr(64 + level) LETTER 
     from dual connect by level <= 26) ALPHABET
   left join 
    (select substr(:input_string, level, 1) INPUT_CHAR 
     from dual connect by level <= length(:input_string)) INPUT_STRING
   on ALPHABET.LETTER = INPUT_STRING.INPUT_CHAR
   order by ALPHABET.LETTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to split and aggregate strings. Just a simple regex_replace will work.

The given string is surrounded by `[^` and `]`, so that any characters that are not in that list will be replaced.

```
SQL> var str varchar2(26);
SQL> exec :str := 'AQ';

SQL> select regexp_replace(
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  '[^'||:str||']'
  ,' '
)                               resulting_str
from dual;

RESULTING_STR
------------------------------
A               Q


SQL> exec :str := 'A';

select regexp_replace(
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  '[^'||:str||']'
  ,' '
)                               resulting_str
from dual;

RESULTING_STR
------------------------------
A


SQL> exec :str := 'Z';

SQL> select regexp_replace(
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  '[^'||:str||']'
  ,' '
)                               resulting_str
from dual;

RESULTING_STR
------------------------------
                         Z
```